# Fixing a formatting issue using Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to convert a string of text that is either 5 or 6 characters long into a date by inserting / at the correct spots for it. I'm having a really hard time getting excel to do this.

I've tried googling this, I tried using Cdate or

```
=IF(LEN(A1)=5,DATE(RIGHT(A1,2),LEFT(A1,1),MID(A,2,2)),0)
```

But they don't return the correct date because it assumes the data is already for the correct date. This seems like it should be so simple to do. It is very simple without using excel, you just type in the / in the 2 spots and it's converted to the correct date.

For example I might have in A1 a string of text like:

```
80715
80715
80715
122515
122515
122515
```

What I want to happen is:

```
8/07/15
8/07/15
8/07/15
12/15/15
12/15/15
12/15/15
```

What I'm thinking about doing (if there isn't a simpler solution) is have a user input the date upfront and then have it fill the range ie:

```
Dim Input1 As Date
Input1 = InputBox("Please Enter the Date", "Input1", 0)
Range("A1").Value = Input1
```

but surely there is an easier way right? Please help me excel geniuses.

Comment: Look at the Format function MsgBox (Format(Input1, "short date")) or MsgBox (Format(Input1, "MM/dd/yyyy")) or MsgBox (Format(Input1, "yyyy/MM/dd")) or whatever format you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this formula:

'string only:

```
=LEFT(RIGHT("0"&A1,6),2) & "/" & MID(RIGHT("0"&A1,6),3,2) & "/" & RIGHT(RIGHT("0"&A1,6),2)

'as date:
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(RIGHT("0"&A1,6),2) & "/" & MID(RIGHT("0"&A1,6),3,2) & "/" & RIGHT(RIGHT("0"&A1,6),2))
```

Comment: This works great, I added a tiny bit to it so it better serves my purposes but I didn't state that before thanks for you response. 

     =TEXT(DATEVALUE(LEFT(RIGHT("0"&A3,6),2)&"/"&MID(RIGHT("0"&A3,6),3,2)&"/"&RIGHT(RIGHT("0"&A3,6),2)),"MM/DD/YY")

Answer (score 2):

You can use the length of the value to determine how many numbers to use for the month and where to start the extraction of the day:

```
=DATE(2000+RIGHT(A1,2),LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-4),MID(A1,LEN(A1)-3,2))
```

This will work for dates in the year 2000 or later, since your string values only include two digits for the year.

Since this returns a date value, make sure your cells are formatted as dates to see the proper date string.